# Does IEventAggregator subscribe multiple times?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-3.0, event-handling, prism

If I have the following Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.IEventAggregator instance:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>.Subscribe(SomeMethod);
```

and the above line of code is hit multiple times, does EventAggregator check if there is already a subscribtion or will this keep subscribing and fire multiple times (everytime) for a single Publish()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should subscribe multiple times.  The `Subscribe` method returns a [`SubscriptionToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.events.subscriptiontoken.aspx) which should be distinct even if you use the call the `Subscribe` with the same method multiple times, allowing you to remove a distinct reference if you choose to do so.

Comment: If you have a base class with the above in it, and there are 5 children inheriting, the above code will subscribe five times.  Does that mean if the event is published once that it will execute 5 times or once?

Comment: @4thSpace: If you have one instance each of the five types, then when the event is published, it will publish five times.  Remember, the handler is tied to the *instance* not the *type*.  If you've created a static method and set the handler to a static method, then it will only be registered once, static constructors are local to the type, not derived types and are only executed once.